# Steam won't working properly on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, games, steam, tar

My Steam won't start on Ubuntu. What I should do?
I installed using

> sudo apt-get install steam

OK,installed fine but... doesn't work, Steam won't open, don't do nothing.

Typed `steam` on Terminal, this is what I got on feedback:

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive
>   xz: (stdin): File format not recognized
>   tar: Child returned status 1
>   tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
>   find: ‘/home/lucasmarra/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime’: No such file or directory

I'm new using Ubuntu, sorry.

Comment: Does  "OK, doesn't work" mean it didn't install or are you referring to what happens when you type `steam` in the terminal?

Comment: Referring that Steam isn't working, won't open. Sorry

Comment: Any help? 10 hours and still here